# NestedScrollView not triggering collapse in AppBarLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design

I have created an Android app based on Chris Banes' [Cheesesquare](https://github.com/chrisbanes/cheesesquare) demo. Instead of having RecyclerViews on one of the fragments inside of the ViewPager, I have a TextView and a NestedScrollView with some scrollable text inside it. When I scroll through the content on the fragments with only the RecyclerView on them, the toolbar collapses properly. On the fragment with the TextView, the toolbar doesn't collapse. If I remove the TextView from the fragment so I just have a NestedScrollView, then scrolling on the fragment will correctly collapse the toolbar.

Here is the CoordinatorLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here is the layout for the fragment where scrolling collapse is not working:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Header"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

<View android:layout_below="@id/header"
    android:id="@+id/header_bar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dip"
    android:background="#000000"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_bar"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. ..."/>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I've spent some time troubleshooting this and it looks like the issue lies in the layout behavior on the AppBarLayout. That class has the following method:

```
public boolean onStartNestedScroll(CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout, AppBarLayout child, View directTargetChild, View target, int nestedScrollAxes) {
    boolean started = (nestedScrollAxes & 2) != 0 && child.hasScrollableChildren() && coordinatorLayout.getHeight() - target.getHeight() <= child.getHeight();
    if(started && this.mAnimator != null) {
        this.mAnimator.cancel();
    }

    return started;
}
```

For scrolls on my NestedScrollView, this method returns false. The reason is that the height of the scroll view must be greater than or equal to the height of the coordinatorLayout - the height of the AppBarLayout. If the scroll view has no siblings, then this will be the case, but if you add any other views to the layout, then it evaluates false and scrolling behavior is deactivated.

I have worked around this by returning true instead and it seems to fix the problem. I am wondering if anyone else has run into this and has any better solutions.